# Check out of, check into - meaning

Tags: meaning, word-usage

> When you are editing a stored program, **check it out of** the source control system
>   and load the checked-out copy into the MySQL Query Browser or other
>   tool.
>
> When you are satisfied with your changes, save the stored program code to a
>   disk file and **check it into** the version control system.

How do you understand these two phrases?

Comment: You may want to check out [ell.se].

Comment: @J.R. The only answer I see on ELL that relates to this shows no understanding of IT jargon. Not that it should.

Comment: @andy256 - Check out this user's [35 questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/69786/user69786?tab=questions), then ask yourself if maybe user69786 could benefit from learning about another Stack Exchange site that might prove beneficial. I never mentioned anything about this question being migrated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Check out** and **check in** are two specific terms used in source control systems.

They are jargon. The first use I encountered was in [RCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_Control_System), in 1982.

The term *check out* derives from a hotel or supermarket [checkout](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/checkout).

To *check out* is to obtain your program from the source control system.

To *check in* is to put your program into the source control system.